# Why ideal containment in the proof of unique ideal factorization?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I want to understand the proof that the number fields (which are dedekind domains) have unique factorization of ideals. I am trying to read this proof here [IDEAL FACTORIZATION - KEITH CONRAD](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf) but..

---

I couldn't understand the reason for the inclusions in this proof:

**Corollary 3.5**: *For any nonzero ideal $\mathfrak b$ and nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$, $\mathfrak {pb} \subseteq \mathfrak b$ with strict inclusion*.

*Proof.* Easily $\mathfrak {pb} \subseteq \mathfrak b$. If $\mathfrak {pb} = \mathfrak b$ then for all $k\ge1$, $\mathfrak b = \mathfrak p^k \mathfrak b$ therefore $\mathfrak b \subseteq \mathfrak p^k$. *rest of proof omitted*

---

First of all these are all ideals of $\mathbb O_K$ the ring of integers of a number field $K$.

How do we know $\mathfrak {pb} \subseteq \mathfrak b$?

How do we know $\mathfrak {b} \subseteq \mathfrak p^k$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\, $ For ideals in a ring $\rm\,R,\,$ divides $\Rightarrow$ contains: $\rm\:I\mid J\:\Rightarrow\: I\supseteq J\:$ since $\rm\:J = I\,K \subseteq I\,R \subseteq I.\:$

(The converse implication is a characteristic property of Dedekind domains).

So, for example, $\:\mathfrak p^k \mathfrak b = \mathfrak b\:\Rightarrow\: \mathfrak p^k\mid \mathfrak b\:\Rightarrow\: \mathfrak p^k \supseteq \mathfrak b$

Comment: I see! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathfrak b$ is an ideal of $\mathbb O_K$ we have $\mathbb O_K \mathfrak b \subseteq \mathfrak b$, since $\mathfrak p$ is a subset of $\mathbb O_K$ we have $\mathfrak p \mathfrak b \subseteq \mathfrak b$.